# UV unwrap high poly object

Tags: uv

I didn't uv unwrap before subdividing, what should I do? how can I uv unwrap it to move it to substance painter? it's not just the object in the picture it's everything but the blade. also how can I subdivide the blade and keep it sharp like it is in the picture for sculpting? [image]

Comment: Do you absolutely need to subdivide? Your shapes seem already round enough. For the unwrap you could simply unwrap with the Smart UV Project option, you don't need a clean unwrap if you just plan to paint on the 3D object in Substance I guess. As for the blade, if you really need to subdivide it, you can first bevel the edge to keep it sharp.

Comment: @moonboots I subdivided all those things to sculpt them, i'll try smart UV project

Comment: OK but it's probably better to keep your object low-poly, can't you sculpt on a high-poly version and save the details with a normal bake?

Comment: @moonboots but baking it would be for a game object no? im just making it as a practice, smart UV project didn't work well it put the seams in bad spots do I need to just unwrap it by myself then and next time unwrap before sculpting?

Comment: Baking is for Blender as well, in order to only keep a low-poly version, which is much easier to work with. Also, it will make the unwrap easier. Smart UV Project is ok if you plan to paint in the Blender or Substance 3D viewport. If you plan to paint on a 2D image editor you need to mark some seams and choose the Unwrap option

Comment: @moonboots yea it's been pretty annoying to work with this haha lagging all the time, I just prefer keeping the details like this instead of baking so it will look better, or am I wrong and don't understand baking 100% still? is there a problem with my settings in blender I have a pretty nice pc with 3070 and it's lagging a lot even when going in and out of edit mode, also thank you for the help

Comment: Baking the normals will keep all the details, except they will be fake 3d, not real 3d, but it should not be a problem and it will allow you to work with a low-poly, which is much lighter

Comment: Even in <name the latest jaw-breaking CGI ultra realistic movie>, they don't use any polygon that is unnecessary.  And looking at your model, it surely does not require any crazy amount of polygons, and certainly doesn't need to apply a subdivision modifier. Use a multires modifier if you just need more mesh density when sculpting, or dyntopo. But besides that, people always work on a low poly version all the time, simply because everything runs faster on simpler meshes, and everything is simpler to do.

Comment: Automated uv unwrapping rarely produce a good uv map. The advantage is that they are done quickly and are fine for static - non-deformable - background props. It's a good solution for quick and dirty stuff. But anything that needs polishing, you want to be in control, make every pixel of your texture worth its memory load, place seems where they are the least visible, and so on.

Comment: @L0Lock so what should I do to get it to lower polly? unsubdivide with multires?